# add multiple input rows in single table

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to store multiple input rows in cake php. but I'm getting an error. Here's my code:

**controller::action:**

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->OrderPlan->create();

    if ($this->OrderPlan->saveAll($this->request->data, 
            array('validation'=>false),
            array('atomic'=>true))) {

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The order plan has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The enquiry could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

**edit page:**

```
 <?php
    $catageries = array("yarn", "knitting", "dyeing", " Compacting ");
    foreach ($catageries as $value):
?>   
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo "$value";?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('work_begin_date', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'work-begin-date', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('work_end_date', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'work-end-date', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('lead_time_from_po', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'lead-time-form-po', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('po_to_be_issued_on_date', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'po-to-be-issued-on-date', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('planned_po_qty', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'planned-po-qty', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('planned_unit_rate', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'planned-unit-rate', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('po_date', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'po-date', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('po_number', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'po-number', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('party_name', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'party-name', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('actual_po_qty', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'actual-po-qty', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('actual_unit_rate', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'span6 datepicker', 'label' => false, 'tabindex' => '1', 'id' => 'actual_unit_rate', 'wrapInput' => false)); ?></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Save All'),array('multiple'=>'true'), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')); ?>
```

This stores only one record in the last row. Another three rows are not saved.

Comment: Can you provide full code of edit.ctp file?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using `Model::saveMany()`, your data needs to be formatted like this

```
Model =>
  0 =>
    field1 => var1
    field2 => var2
  1 =>
    field1 => var3
    field2 => var4
```

in order to do that, your form fields need indexes, like this

```
$this->Form->input('Model.0.field1')
$this->Form->input('Model.0.field2')
$this->Form->input('Model.1.field1')
$this->Form->input('Model.1.field2')
```

**edit**: example code
you may adapt your original code with something like this

```
$i = 0;
foreach($categories as $category){
    echo $this->Form->input('Model.' .$i. '.field1');
    echo $this->Form->input('Model.' .$i. '.field2');
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are saving multiple rows then you have to unset last saved item's id. Use
`$this->Model->save();` 
and then use

```
 unset($this->Model->id);
```

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong way. In order to reset a models state, one uses [`Model::create()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-create-array-data-array), however, he's not using multiple `Model::save()` calls, but [`Model::saveAll()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array), so the problem is actually the format of the data, wich has to be [`Model::saveMany()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array) compatible.